# Adding values from a arrayList to shared Preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Is it possible for me to store and retrieve my ArrayList values using shared preference. Can anyone suggest me with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the closest the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) can do is save a `Set` of `String`s. If that doesn't suit you should probably look at [the alternatives](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for persisting data.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this : http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.com/2011/07/store-and-get-object-in-android-shared.html (Thanks to Greg Zimmers that give this tutorial).

The idea is you encapsulate the ArrayList to an Object and then you can refer to link tutorial that I give above and follow the tutorial. If you want to retrieve the ArrayList, you can get the Object and then you retrieve the ArrayList from the Object.