# Store a List or Set in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, list, sharedpreferences

My app has a list of String values (of some 5-20 characters each), that I have to store persistently. The SharedPreferences seem to me the most appropriate, as it's a short list. Usually it will be empty, or contain just a few values.

I've already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274480/adding-values-from-a-arraylist-to-shared-preference) which asks basically the same, the answer is unsuitable as the StringSet is API level 11, and I'm targeting Android 2.1 and up, which is API 7.

Considering the usually small list of strings, using a database seems total overkill to me. Using a file to store this would be another solution but not so elegant. I've considered creating keys (like "1", "2", "3", etc) but that's actually worse than using a file - especially when it comes to reading back my data.

Anyway if nothing else works I'll have to go for the file option. If my idea is simply not practical using the SharedPreferences for API lvl 7, I'd appreciate to hear that too.

Comment: What's wrong with this one. Serialize the Collection in String and put it in SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 31):

I found the easiest solution to store and retrieve a list of items from SharedPreferences is to simply serialize / deserilaize the array into / from JSON and store it into a string setting.

Gson comes really handy doing it.

READ:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String value = prefs.getString("list", null);

GsonBuilder gsonb = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = gsonb.create();
MyObject[] list = gson.fromJson(value, MyObject[].class);
```

WRITE:

```
String value = gson.toJson(list);
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor e = prefs.edit();
e.putString("list", value);
e.commit();
```

Comment: You can use JSONObject/JSONArray too, which is included in Android by default, so no extra libs necessary.

Comment: Need urgent help, how to get the list from the Shared preference !
Directly to a List @Drejc

Comment: How to Define MyObject Class!

Comment: Ok ... you are skipping ahead of yourself. First make sure that the class you try to write/read from the preferences can be serialized/deserialized into JSON - the class itself should be a simple value holding class (without any internal logic). Read up on JSON serialization with Gson. Once you have your Array MyObject[] you can transform it into a List<MyObject> with Arrays.asList()

Answer (score 18):

Using this object --> [TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo)  its very simple.

```
TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(context);
```

to put

```
tinydb.putList("MyUsers", mUsersArray);
```

to get

```
tinydb.getList("MyUsers");
```

Comment: how would getList be used in another class though?

Comment: just use the same key you used in saving it. it doesn't matter which class you're in as long as its the same app.

Comment: That's just... ew. It joins the array with a key, that it assumes, will never be used. Ew.

Answer (score 8):

If you know the order of the list entries and/or it doesn't matter you can "glue" them all into a single String with a separator of your choice and then store it with `SharedPreferences`. After loading it back you would split the String into the entries based on your separator. Something like `String listEntries = "enty1;entry2;entry3"` (semicolon as separator in this case). But no idea about performance issues.

Comment: Order doesn't matter. Basically same idea as when storing in a file but this is a little cleaner indeed. Will consider.

Comment: Hack!  There's gotta be a better way, right?  Anyone?  Bueller ... Bueller?

Sigh, I'll probably have to do it that way (sooo OLD-school!).