# Store and get data with SharedPreferences

Tags: android, arrays, string, url, sharedpreferences

I would like to store and recall user's favorite links from string.xml how can I do this?

I would like clarify that the user only enter a name for favourite url, for example, sports it will be associated with the page that the user is currently viewing on my app (ex. www.sport.com)

my string.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">MyApp</string>
    <string-array name="Name_Fav"></string-array>
    //Here I would like to store the names of url favorites
    //<item >Sport</item>
    <string-array name="Url_Fav"></string-array>
    //Here I would like to store full url
    //<item >www.sport.com</item>
</resources>
```

in my activity

```
public void onClick(View v) {
String[] name_url = //Items retrieved from Name_Fav (sport)
String[] url_fav = //items retrieved from Url_FAv (www.sport.com)
//now here I would like to put and retrieve the data from the resource file
}
```

---

**Edit:** I found the solution here:
[Store a List or Set in SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598331/store-a-list-or-set-in-sharedpreferences)

Comment: what do you want to exactly? Write your problem exactly

Comment: -1 for not searching how to use SharedPreferences.

Comment: i have read more examples but ALL retrieve a single string instead array string from resources file so do not go well to solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the examples [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)?

If you need to store something more complex than just simple preferecnes, you should probably just store the stuff into a [database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db).

Comment: my problem is slightly different because I do not know the number of url to be retrieved and also their name, I can't find an example that retrieves a string array only string with constant name

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand your question, but I've modified my answer to try to address it.